# Joomla 1.5 enable news on main page

Tags: joomla, module, components, virtuemart

Good Afternoon. I've got a Joomla 1.5 + VirtueMart shop. There were "Top Sale" product on the main page. I've disabled this module, but I don't know how to enable news showing on the main page.

I've already flagged materials to show it on the main page) and tried to change template to default.

thx

**UPD:** I need to have a pagenav every 10 articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The news is a module ,

then Go to module manager set the proper position and menu assignment section set Home page.

If you are added new position then edit the template file and add your new position there too.

like `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="your_custom_position" />`

This much is required to display a module on a proper page make sure module is published.

hope its helps..

Comment: No, I just need to show news on the main page like in a category. I tried to use **mod_lastnews**, but it looks like inform block, not like category

Comment: you can override the styles of a default mod_lastnew with your custom styles http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: I found the solution. I need to add **home Menu**. But I don't know, how to put it into template...

Comment: Create a home menu on menu manager and go to module manager assign menu section with proper menu then on template page set the module position like above(Ans)